# Select flag to indicate if each field in bottom 10 percent in access sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table which lists scores for each employee across a range of performance areas (KPIs). I have written a query which returns these scores as well as 'flag' fields indicating if they were in the bottom 10 percent for each KPI per business area. The query is working but seems overly complex (the example below shows 3 KPIs but the actual version has many more):

```
SELECT [Employee Number], [Full Name], [Business Area], 

[Absence],
IIF([Employee Number] in (
    SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT [Employee Number]
    FROM tblKPIScores as a
    WHERE a.[Business Area] = tblKPIScores.[Business Area]
    ORDER BY Absence DESC
),"Y","N") AS AbsenceFlag,

[Complaints], 
IIF([Employee Number] in (
    SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT [Employee Number]
    FROM tblKPIScores as b
    WHERE b.[Business Area] = tblKPIScores.[Business Area]
    ORDER BY Complaints DESC
),"Y","N") AS ComplaintsFlag,

[Service Time],
IIF([Employee Number] in (
    SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT [Employee Number]
    FROM tblKPIScores as c
    WHERE c.[Business Area] = tblKPIScores.[Business Area]
    ORDER BY [Service Time] DESC
),"Y","N") AS [Service Time Flag]

FROM tblKPIScores
```

I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of writing this instead of having to do a separate sub query for each KPI?

Comment: You might be able to write a function to take the table and field name and a top "how_ever_many" value to return the flag. It would probably be easier to maintain.

Comment: @Minty thanks for the reply. Yes a VBA function is definitely one option. I currently copy the output of the query into an excel spreadsheet to be distributed to the business and so the column layout (and efficiency) of an SQL query is convenient to me. I may consider moving to VBA if it many more KPIs are added and it becomes too cumbersome. I was hoping to streamline the query itself but I'm not sure if it can be simplified any further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using derived tables, one for each KPI. You can even save each derived table as a separate saved query, replacing the nested `SELECT` statements in `LEFT JOIN` clauses. This would be a more efficient solution as no longer do you run correlated subqueries nested in `IIF()` for each row value.

Note: Access SQL requires parentheses wrapped for each `JOIN` parings; hence for complex queries it is better to predesign joins in query's *Design View*:

```
SELECT t.[Employee Number], t.[Full Name], t.[Business Area], 
       t.[Absence], IIF(a.AbsenceEmpNum IS NOT NULL, 'Y', 'N') AS AbsenceFlag,
       t.[Complaints],  IIF(a.ComplaintsEmpNum IS NOT NULL, 'Y', 'N') AS ComplaintsFlag,
       t.[Service Time], IIF(a.ServiceTimeEmpNum IS NOT NULL, 'Y', 'N') AS ServiceTimeFlag

FROM ((tblKPIScores t

LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT sub.[Employee Number] As AbsenceEmpNum
    FROM tblKPIScores as sub
    ORDER BY sub.Absence DESC) AS a
ON t.[Employee Number] = a.AbsenceEmpNum)

LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT sub.[Employee Number] As ComplaintsEmpNum
    FROM tblKPIScores as sub
    ORDER BY sub.Complaints DESC) AS c
ON t.[Employee Number] = c.ComplaintsEmpNum)

LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT sub.[Employee Number] As ServiceTimeEmpNum
    FROM tblKPIScores as sub
    ORDER BY sub.[Service Time] DESC) AS s
ON t.[Employee Number] = s.ServiceEmpNum
```

Comment: Thanks for this. One of the reasons I was hoping to simplify the query was to reduce the amount of code written (ideally have a query that once written can handle any number of KPIs, although at this point I'm not sure that that's possible). Your query doesn't seem to be any shorter than mine. Is there any other advantage to doing it this way that I've overlooked?

Comment: Oh no. I should have mentioned. This solution no longer uses correlated subqueries (running the calculation for each row value) but join tables on most likely an index field, *Employee Number*, so should run more efficiently.

Comment: By the way, your problem is actually a design issue. Had you maintained one column for KPI *Types* and second for *Scores* and not separate  columns like *Absence*, *Complaints*, *Service Time*, you could use a crosstab (dynamic pivot) for all KPIs. Look up normalization.

Comment: Ah ok, that's great advice. I will redesign my tables and use a cross tab query. Thanks!